# sobol random no. generater python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I want to generate random no. using Sobol, I found this page, but I don't know how to use it. How can I use this https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/sobol/sobol.html to generate random no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the lines:

```
from sobol import *

seed = 12345 # is is basically index in the sobol sequence
ndim = 1 # dimension of the problem

for _ in range(0, 10):
    [srn, seed] = i4_sobol(ndim, seed)
    print(srn)
```

PS Ah, I see you're using python-3, it won't work for a time being, it is in python-2. If you could wait, I'll take a look at it in ~10 hours

Comment: module imported

Comment: @user1779646 I looked inside the module and it still uses old style `print` and few other things - clearly, python-2 module. So you either hack it yourself or could wait when I could hack it for python-3

Comment: @user1779646 U're welcome. Besides print, I would check // vs / division difference introduced with Python 3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4044696/severin-pappadeux, Hi was simulating an addition-subtraction game, and to get  random negative values, I  did this  
    [ i, seed ] = i4_uniform ( 0, 100, seed )

    j = i4_bit_hi1 ( i )

    if j%2 == 0:
        bit = 1
        return(bit)

    elif j%2 != 0:
        bit = -1
        return(bit)    IS THIS CORRECT IMPLIMENTATION

Comment: stackoverflow.com/users/4044696/severin-pappadeux this function return the location of high bit, and if high bit%2 == 0, multiply random number by -1

Comment: @user1779646 ok, I'll look at it this evening, about 8-9 hours from now

Comment: Ok, I looked at your code, and , frankly, it doesn't look right. Why do you want to return either positive or negative random value based on LOCATION of high bit? Again, this is LOCATION of the bit, bit itself is always 1, and it is not distributed uniformly, I believe. Anyway, I've ported Sobol to Python3, if you still need it, I could drop it somewhere

Comment: so, is there any way to sobol choice between 2 values like random.choice(). And bit is not always 1, though it could be not uniform.

Comment: @user1779646 but you're looking at bit POSITION (LOCATION)! i4_bit_hi1() returns POSITION of the highest bin in the integer. If you need a choice, what about `if (i4_sobol(...) > 0.5): return i4_sobol(...) else: return -i4_sobol(...)`

Comment: if sobol > 0.5 return (+), else return (-) , but in this case higher values will always be positive and lower negatives, its not random.

Comment: @user1779646 well, you have to use two random numbers for that - first call for sign selection, second for value itself